# How to convert host byte order IP address to ASCII IP x.x.x.x in KQL

Tags: kql

I am getting IP values as host byte order and want to convert it to normal IP address as 192.168.1.1 using KQL.

Input1: -1979811809
Output: x.x.x.x

Input2: 167772448
Output: x.x.x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

If you only want to convert positive numbers, then you can do this:

`print format_ipv4(167772448, 32)` will output `10.0.1.32`.

If you want to convert both positive and negative numbers, you'll need to take the least-significant 4 bytes of the number, by doing the following:

`print format_ipv4(binary_and(0xffffffff, -1407228728), 32)` will output `172.31.100.200`.

See more details on the format_ipv4() function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-ipv4-function

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. It worked.
Could you please help with -1979811809 as well. I think minus (-) is adding for Private IP. I am not able convert it.

Comment: What IP would you expect to get as an output for -1979811809 (and please explain your answer)?

Comment: Actually we are getting two IP addresses as below. comms_ip is public ip of asset and interface_ip is private ip of asset. Using fomat_ipv4 function i am able to convert comms_ip but unfortunately it is not working for interface_ip.

comms_ip_d: xxxxxxxxxx Output: x.x.x.x (format_ipv4 function working)

interface_ip_d: -1407228728, Expected otput: 172.31.100.200

Comment: How do you get from -1407228728 to 172.31.100.200? Is there a doc explaining this? If this is something standard, we'll modify the `format_ipv4` function to correctly handle negative numbers.

Comment: Please refer below link and search for 32-bit signed long. CB API provides output in this format for IP address. From CB console i can confirm that -1407228728 belongs to 172.31.100.200. Could you please help.
https://developer.carbonblack.com/reference/enterprise-response/6.3/rest-api/

Comment: I've updated the answer to work with negative numbers too.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear that. Please accept the answer :)